# can the top, bottom etc of Positioned widget in a stack be specified as percentage?

Tags: flutter, dart

When using the Positioned widget in flutter, can I specify the top and bottom parameter as a percentage of the stack instead of exact pixels?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just try it to find out yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Idea! I don't know, how do you like it.

You can't use percentages directly for exact pixels.
but you can use MediaQuery to use percentages.

final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size; //this var has 100% of your screen

now you can use a percentage of your screenSize in the top, bottom, right, and left properties.

like
top: size.height / 2,   //it will be divide your screenHeight by 2 means 50%

Comment: Thanks, this method helped me figure out a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestions :

first :
in the Stack Widget, there is an `alignment` property, where you can choose a value from the `Alignment` enum to align the `Positioned` widget
you can also wrap `Positioned` widget with `Align` widget

if this doesn't fit in your case
in that `alignment` property you can use `Alignment` constructor to specify a y and x values to align your widget, so in example :

```
alignment: Alignment(0, 0)
```

will center your widget

```
alignment: Alignment(-1, -1)
```

will align your widget to the left top

```
alignment: Alignment(1, 1)
```

will align your widget to the right bottom

with this, you can use those between those values to get into a specific alignment
with multiplying by your calculated percentage to get into specific align based on %

Comment: 1, 1 is right bottom, not right top.